# Does Thanos's ship land in the middle of the battlefield in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the movie *Avengers: Endgame*, does Thanos's ship, Sanctuary 2,

> come crashing down right in the middle of the battlefield on Earth after Captain Marvel flies through it? If it did, wouldn't it have crushed a lot of the combatants, and wouldn't it have likely caused everyone else to be blown off the battlefield due to like a 400 mph wind gust that would have come rushing outwards from the ship's impact with the ground since the Sanctuary 2 was so massive?

Comment: It’s a film where magic flying gods can go to different worlds in seconds, I doubt a bit of wind would affect them much.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, good point. I bet Thanos was thinking 'damn! I just made the last payment on that thing!' as it he watched it fall.

Comment: I sure hope Thanos had insured his ship!

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - Technically, being defeated by Thor is considered an 'act of god'

Comment: @Valorum Hmm, hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @Valorum And definitely not a belly-flop. Nope.

Comment: These are the weirdest spoiler tags/title combination

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Not quite

Actually, it crashes into the river which was next to the battlefield in New York state.

[image]

Comment: And if I recall correctly this is also what caused the flood/tidal wave that forced Dr. Strange out of the "big battle" by needing him to stop the water from drowning everyone?